# MethodNotFound exception on Tomcat 7 with JSF2

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat7

I'm developing with JSF2 in Netbeans 7cr1 and Tomcat.7.0.11 ... the app starts up ok but as soon as I use anything that has EL behind (like command button invoking a bean's method to return a property) I get a `MethodNotFound` exception.

When running on Glassfish I had no such issues. I've read somewhere that I's got to to with el-impl.jar that comes with Tomcat and that is needs to be replaced. Is that true and if so could someone kindly point me towards the most relevant release of that library as been trying to find one but seems like there are more than one.

Answer (score 0):

The EL action method expression should look like this:

```
<h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
```

See, no parentheses and other clutter.

The bean action method signature should look like this:

```
public String submit() {
    return "foo";
}
```

See, no arguments and a `String` outcome (`void` is also permitted).

---

Probably you was using

```
<h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit()}" />
```

which will indeed not work when your `web.xml` is declared as per Servlet 2.5 instead of Servlet 3.0. You need to ensure that your `web.xml` is declared conform Servlet 3.0.

Comment: Hi BalusC,

Thanks for your tips though it's got nothing to do with using parenthesis (I've not use any) . The application runs fine under Glassfish ... the problems begin when I run under tomcat 7 and Mojarra ... it start's out just fine but the moment I invoke an action with EL behind I get EL exception from Tomcat saying MethodNotFound ... I am sure there's something I either haven't configured right or most likely it's got to to with the Tomcat's shipped el-api.jar (which by the way I have already tried to replace with Glassfishe's el-api.jar and el-impl. in the Tomcat's /lib directory b